# Press TouchableOpacity that is underneath a view

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to display an image over a TouchableOpacity  but with the image over the TouchableOpacity takes priority over the button. Is there anyway around this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you need an Image to be touchable nest it in the TouchableOpacity. If you are trying to have an Image as the Touchable Opacity background try

```
<TouchableOpacity>
  <ImageBackground source={image} style={styles.image}/>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I haven't used [ImageBackground](https://reactnative.dev/docs/imagebackground) so you may need to check out the docs